# change the output format of the time elapsed between two hours

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have the following SQL Query:

```
    SELECT 
    TO_CHAR(Event1, 'HH24:MI:SS'),
    TO_CHAR(Event2, 'HH24:MI:SS'),
    TO_CHAR((Event1-Event2) * -1440) AS Elapsed
...
```

This gives me the time elapsed between the two hours at which event1 and event2 happened in minutes.

My question: how do I enforce the time elapsed to be displayed not in minutes but in the following format `HH24:MI:SS`?

Comment: I presume you are using Oracle from the `to_char` function.  It is a good idea to tag all questions with the database engine you are using.

Comment: Sorry not to mention that, it's an Oracle database.

Comment: Do event1 and event2 are a date type?

Comment: Yes, both of them are DATE types.

Comment: Well if I multiply the result *24 I will get the elapsed time in hours, but most of the time the numbers that I get are quite big and need rounding up, while if I multiply by 1440 I get a whole number most of the time...and it's negative, because for some reason all the results I get are negative, if I don't multiply by -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could convert to TIMESTAMP which result in an interval datatype

```
SQL> create table test(a date, b date);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values (sysdate - 1.029384, sysdate);

1 row created.

SQL> select 1440*(b-a) diff_in_secs from test;

DIFF_IN_SECS
------------
  1482.31667

SQL> select (cast(b as timestamp)-cast(a as timestamp)) diff_in_secs from test;

DIFF_IN_SECS
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
+000000001 00:42:19.000000
```

you can extract individual elements with `extract('hour' from your_interval_expression)` etc.

```
SQL> select extract(day from diff)||'d '||extract(hour from diff)||'h '||extract(minute from diff)||'m '||extract(second from diff)||'s' from (select (cast(b as timestamp)-cast
(a as timestamp)) diff from test);

EXTRACT(DAYFROMDIFF)||'D'||EX
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1d 0h 42m 19s
```

Comment: You could also use `numtodsinterval(b - a, 'DAY')` to get an `INTERVAL` representation.

Comment: true yes you can do that too.

Comment: numtodsinterval(event2 - event1, 'DAY') works great, but the results that I get now are in the form: 0 2:29:59.9999999
Any ideas how to get rid of the leading 0 (guess it means 0days elapsed), because I dont really need that and how to round up the seconds to a whole number?

Comment: @user1812543 - not sure how you got fractional seconds from subtracting two dates; I can't get that unless I pass in .10416666666666 rather than the date expression. What platform/version are you on? Do you get the same value with DazzaL's original `cast` suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
select 
TRUNC(event1-event2)||':'||
TRUNC(MOD(event1-event2),1)*24)||':'||
TRUNC(MOD(MOD(event1-event2),1)*24,1)*60)||':'||
TRUNC(MOD(MOD(MOD((event1-event2),1)*24,1)*60,1)*60) as elapsed
```